# Using char variables in other methods *edited*

Tags: c#, variables, methods, console-application, pass-by-reference

I am trying to get a string of characters from the user and turn them into a phone number.

We haven't gone over arrays in class yet so I don't want to use anything like that in this program. I don't know much about them yet either. We went over passing references, but I didn't really understand it.

My question is how do I use my char variables in my other methods? I have tried putting the variable under the class and that didn't work either. The most common error message I am receiving is:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Damian_CIS170B_Lab4
{
    class Program
    {
        //char char1;

       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("****Phone Dialing Program****\n");

            char char1;

                //char2, char3, char4, char5, char6, char7;

            GetInput(ref char1);
            ProcessInput();
            ToDigit();
            ShowResults();

            Console.Read();
        }

        static void GetInput(ref char1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your first character:");
            Console.ReadLine() = char.Parse(char1);

           /* Console.WriteLine("Enter your second character:");
              Console.WriteLine("Enter your third character:");
              Console.WriteLine("Enter your fourth character:");
              Console.WriteLine("Enter your fifth character:");
              Console.WriteLine("Enter your sixth character:");
              Console.WriteLine("Enter your seventh character:"); */
        }    

        static void ProcessInput()
        {
        }

        static void ToDigit()
        {
        }

        static void ShowResults()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

So I went with this

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your first character:");
            char1 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

2/25/14
When I use this It only gets the 1st character entered. I am able to enter 2 though 7 but when I try to get it to write all of the characters it only writes the first one, why is that? How can I fix this? 
New code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("****Phone Dialing Program****\n");

        char char1 = default(char);
        char char2 = default(char);
        char char3 = default(char);
        char char4 = default(char);
        char char5 = default(char);
        char char6 = default(char);
        char char7 = default(char);


        GetInput(ref char1, char2, char3, char4, char5, char6, char7);
        ProcessInput(ref char1, char2, char3, char4, char5, char6, char7);
        //ToDigit(ref char1, char2, char3, char4, char5, char6, char7);
        ShowResults();


        Console.Read();
    }

    static void GetInput(ref char char1, char char2, char char3, char char4, char char5, char char6, char char7)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your first character:");
        char1 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your second character:");
        char2 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your third character:");
        char3 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your fourth character:");
        char4 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your fifth character:");
        char5 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your sixth character:");
        char6 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your seventh character:");
        char7 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        ToDigit(ref char1, char2, char3, char4, char5, char6, char7);

    }

    static void ProcessInput(ref char char1, char char2, char char3, char char4, char char5, char char6, char char7)
    {
        char[] chars = { char1, char2, char3, char4, char5, char6, char7 };
        string enteredChars = new string(chars);

        //This is me just trying to see if it is working... its not :(
        Console.WriteLine("This is what you entered: {0}", enteredChars);

    }

    static void ToDigit(ref char char1, char char2, char char3, char char4, char char5, char char6, char char7)
    {
        switch(char1)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
            case 'B':
            case 'b':
            case 'C':
            case 'c':
            case '2': Console.WriteLine("\n2");
                break;
            default: Console.WriteLine("\n");
                break;
        }

    }

    static void ShowResults()
    {
    }
```

Comment: Well with your commented out field, that's an *instance* variable (i.e. it's associated with an instance of your type) but all your methods are *static* methods - you never actually create an instance of `Program`.

Comment: Do you have to use `ref`?  It'd be easier, and cleaner without it

Comment: Thanks selman22 and NewHire! that worked it finally compiled!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method should be like:

```
static void GetInput(ref char char1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your first character:");
    char1 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
}
```

You are missing data type in the parameters.

Then call it like:

```
char char1 = default(char);
GetInput(ref char1);
```

In your method you don't need `char.Parse`, instead I believe you are trying to get a character input from user, that should be done like:

```
char1 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

You can also modify your method to get `char` back, instead of sending the parameter with `ref` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify parameter type here, this won't compile:

```
static void GetInput(ref char1)
```

It should be something like:

```
static void GetInput(ref char char1)
```

Then before you pass a variable as ref parameter to a function,you should initialize it,that means you should give it to a defaul value:

```
char char1 = default(char);
```

Then you can pass it to your function:

```
GetInput(ref char1);
```

If you want to use this variable in your other functions, instead of using `ref` I would define my methods as extension method and return the result `char`, something like this:

```
public static class MyCharExtensions
{
    public static char GetInput()
    {
        return Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    }
    public static char ProcessInput(this char source)
    {
        // do your work with char and return it
    }
    public static char ToDigit(this char source)
    {
        // do your work with char and return it
    }
    public static void ShowResults(this char source)
    {

    }
}
```

And use them like this:

```
MyCharExtensions.GetInput().ProcessInput().ShowResults();
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing by reference allows your method to change the value and have that value reflected outside the method, however it still requires that there be a value coming in.  The error you are describing is because you have not initialized `char1`.  There are two easy ways to resolve this, the first would be to initialize char1 : `char char1 = 'x';`.  The other would be to change from passing by reference to passing as an output parameter.  For your purpose the distinction between `ref` and `output` is that ref expects the value to be initialized before the method is called, and output expects it to be initialized somewhere within the method being called.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use `ref`?  If not, just have `GetInput` return a `char` instead of void.  This may be a start for you :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("****Phone Dialing Program****\n");

        char first = GetInput("first");
        char second = GetInput("second");
        char third = GetInput("third");
        char fourth = GetInput("fourth");
        char fifth = GetInput("fifth");
        char sixth = GetInput("sixth");
        char seventh = GetInput("seventh");
        char eighth = GetInput("eigth");

        Console.Write(new string(new []{first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eighth}));

        Console.Read();
    }

    static char GetInput(string count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your " + count + " character:");
        return Console.ReadLine()[0];
    }
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work... I agree it would make my code look a lot cleaner though.